# Можно ли назначить псевдокласс hover на псевдоэлемент?

Tags: html, css, hover, webkit, scrollbar

У меня есть некоторый элемент `textarea`. Я изменил стили его скроллбара с помощью псевдоэлементов `-webkit-scrollbar-*`. Как я могу при наведении на скроллбар изменить курсор на grab? Другими словами, мне нужно что-то типа

```
#questionBodyTextArea::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    cursor: grab;
}
```

Это вообще возможно?

```css
#questionBodyTextArea::-webkit-scrollbar {
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 10px;
}

#questionBodyTextArea::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #ccc;
}

#questionBodyTextArea::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    cursor: grab;
}

#questionBodyTextArea::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="questionBodyTextArea">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras nec metus sagittis lectus semper commodo. Donec dignissim felis vitae iaculis consequat. Proin rhoncus placerat quam ut condimentum. Proin scelerisque odio id nisi malesuada, in viverra libero placerat. Aliquam at viverra nibh. Ut lacinia gravida lorem, non fermentum dui pellentesque vitae. Suspendisse eget est nec turpis rutrum euismod ac nec erat. Suspendisse vestibulum, elit sit amet maximus gravida, dolor risus cursus massa, vitae vulputate nibh purus et urna. Duis non maximus elit, ut sagittis mauris.Nam fringilla sed tortor quis placerat. Mauris velit enim, suscipit sit amet tincidunt et, mollis eu magna. Nam vel sodales risus. Donec convallis vitae leo ornare accumsan. Cras sed commodo justo, eget posuere nisi. Nullam suscipit commodo laoreet. Aenean malesuada ac odio efficitur ornare. Vestibulum auctor elit at sagittis lacinia. Morbi vel est nec tortor vulputate porttitor. Praesent convallis commodo porta. Donec justo lorem, porta quis tincidunt eu, venenatis vitae turpis. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse vitae aliquam orci. Ut malesuada nisi neque, sit amet faucibus leo volutpat eu. Proin pulvinar dui sed dolor posuere, et feugiat mi congue.Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vestibulum vel lectus fringilla, ullamcorper ipsum ut, sollicitudin dolor. Phasellus pulvinar interdum mollis. Aliquam accumsan, eros sed tincidunt fermentum, nulla magna porta purus, vel ultricies velit orci sit amet velit. Quisque sit amet ex nec erat imperdiet vulputate. Pellentesque iaculis id mauris et hendrerit. Nam egestas tristique dolor, id sagittis sem molestie non. Morbi sodales non metus tincidunt aliquam. Pellentesque nec est nec sapien hendrerit vulputate eget sit amet ipsum. Suspendisse potenti.</textarea>
```

Comment: вот [этим плагином](https://github.com/malihu/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin) воспользуйтесь, забудите о проблемах вообще

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут описано что нельзя на скроллбаре ставить свой курсор -

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23764646/change-cursor-image-on-scrollbar-in-chrome

Можно разве что для `textarea` добавить `cursor: auto`, тогда на скроллбаре будет стрелка